# How to disable the enter key for a p:commandButton?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` that actually is the logout button. It is placed in the north `p:layoutUnit` and if I press the enter key in any form it always log me out. I dont want that button to respond the enter key. How to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Put a hidden button with no action in the logout form and capture the enter key via `p:defaultCommand`.

```
<p:defaultCommand target="dummy"/>
<p:commandButton id="dummy" process="@none" global="false" style="display:none;"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Nest the button within this form tag:

```
<h:form id="thisform" onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13){event.keyCode=0;}">
```