# Primefaces Press Enter executes commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am working with primefaces and I have the following problem, I have a toolbar with several buttons and components like inputtext and others in the form, but when I press the key <kbd>Enter</kbd> in some component the first button of the toolbar is called, in this case commandbutton "idButtomNuevo" is called because it is in the first position.

My code:

almacen.xhtml

```
<ui:composition  
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

 <h:form id="idFormAlmacen" >
    <p:focus context="idFormAlmacen"/>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="2500" for="keyAlmacen" globalOnly="true"/>
    <p:panel header="Almacen" styleClass="texto-panel"/>
    <ui:include src="/pages/logistica/almacen/toolbar_almacen.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="#{almacenBean.pathbodyAlmacen}" />    
 </h:form>
 <ui:include src="/pages/logistica/almacen/dialogos_almacen.xhtml" />
</ui:composition>
```

toolbar_almacen.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:toolbar>  
        <p:toolbarGroup align="left" styleClass="panelgrid-css">
            <p:commandButton id="idButtomNuevo" title="Nuevo"  icon="ui-icon-document" process="@this" value="Nuevo"
                    actionListener="#{almacenBean.limpiarAlmacen}" update="idFormAlmacen" immediate="true">
                 <p:resetInput target="idFormAlmacen"/>
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="idButtomGuardar" title="Guardar" icon="ui-icon-disk" action="#{almacenBean.guardarAlmacen}" 
                 disabled="#{almacenBean.au.btGuardarDisabled}" update=":idFormAlmacen" validateClient="true" value="Guardar"/>
            <p:commandButton id="idButtomEliminar" title="Eliminar" icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{almacenBean.eliminarAlmacen}"
                 disabled="#{almacenBean.au.btGuardarDisabled}" update="idFormAlmacen" process="@this" immediate="true"
                 value="Eliminar"/>
            <p:commandButton id="idButtomListar" title="Listar" icon="ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal" process="@this" value="Listar"
                             actionListener="#{almacenBean.listarAlmacen}" update="idFormAlmacen" immediate="true"/>
            <p:commandButton id="idButtomBuscar" title="Buscar" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Buscar"
                             actionListener="#{almacenBean.buscarAlmacen}" immediate="true">
                <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="idFormAlmacen"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:toolbarGroup>  
    </p:toolbar>
 </ui:composition>
```

pathbodyAlmacen = "/pages/logistica/almacen/crear_almacen.xhtml"

```
<ui:composition  
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

  <p:panel header="Datos Generales de Almacen" />  
  <h:panelGrid id="idPanelAlmacen1" columns="3" width="100%" border="0" columnClasses="colC1-T,colC2-T">
    <p:outputLabel  for="idEmpresa" value="Empresa:" style="margin-right:2px;"/>  
    <p:inputText id="idEmpresa"  style="width:350px;" value="#{almacenBean.alVista.strEmpresa}" readonly="true"/>  
    <h:outputText value="&#160;&#160;&#160;"/>

    <p:outputLabel for="idCodProveedor" value="Codigo:" style="margin-right:2px;"/>  
    <p:inputText id="idCodProveedor" value="#{almacenBean.alVista.codigo}" style="width:350px;" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Ingrese Codigo ">
        <p:clientValidator />
    </p:inputText>  
    <p:message for="idCodProveedor" display="text"/>

    <p:outputLabel for="idNombre" value="Nombre:" style="margin-right:2px;"/>  
    <p:inputText id="idNombre" value="#{almacenBean.alVista.nombre}" style="width:350px;"
                 required="true" requiredMessage="Ingrese Nombre de Almacen">
        <p:clientValidator event="keyup" />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message for="idNombre" display="text"/>
  </h:panelGrid>

  <h:panelGrid id="idPgDirAlmacen" columns="4" width="100%" border="0" columnClasses="colC1-T,colC2-T,colC3">
    <p:outputLabel for="idInDirAlmacen" value="Direccion de Almacen:" style="margin-right:2px;" />
    <p:inputText id="idInDirAlmacen" style="width:350px;" readonly="true" required="true"  value="#{almacenBean.alVista.direccionAlmacen}"
                 requiredMessage="Ingrese direccion de Almacen"/>   
    <p:commandButton title="Crear Direccion Almacen" actionListener="#{almacenBean.abrirDireccionAlmacen}"  process="@this"
                     icon="ui-icon-search" >
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update=":idFormAlmacen:idPgDirAlmacen"/>
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:message for="idInDirAlmacen" display="text"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

thanks for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue in my project. To avoid the submit on enter key press I just did like following.
At **every inputText field** added this code,

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }"
```

Comment: Why on EVERY inputText when you can do it on the form (like in the other anser). Care to add why you do it in a more complex way?

Answer (score 24):

This is not a JSF specific behavior, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed the first `<input>` with `type="submit"` is used. This has been discussed on SO (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/jsf-default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142033/how-to-disable-the-enter-key-for-a-pcommandbutton)), I'll put here some of the suggestions from those threads.

*Javascript solution:*

Use `<h:form id="thisform" onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13){event.keyCode=0;}">` on your form. This, however, will prevent you from having any default command on the form since it catches pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*Primefaces solution:*

Use a dummy button on the form which does nothing, and set it as form's default command.

```
<p:defaultCommand target="dummy"/>
<p:commandButton id="dummy" process="@none" global="false" style="display:none;"/>
```

Comment: However if the focus is in a button and I press enter in both cases is not called the action of the button with the focus.
Excume me for my English

Comment: Try this for first example: `onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13){if(document.activeElement.type == 'text') event.keyCode=0;}"`

Comment: Thanks, but I try with : `onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13){if(document.activeElement.type == 'text') return false;}"` and it's working, with `event.keyCode=0` doesn't work